# Creating disk files causes the free memory to become small in docker

Tags: java, linux, docker

Creating disk files causes the free memory to become small.But,the java process still work with no OOM.The memory will get better after deleting the disk file with command 'rm'.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uhIF.png)
env:
jdk:jdk8u202
linux:CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
docker:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Creating files does not necessarily mean a jump in memory usage, rather keeping or loading entire files in memory would increase memory usage. Once memory has been allocated to the JVM it is not easily released because the JVM expects to use a similar amount of memory for future actions, this is normal and expected behaviour. I don't know how your code operations, and why 'rm' causes memory to be freed, but it is likely related to your code. If you want specific information please show the code, and include more information about what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: Is it possible that somme processes stopped when you removed the log file, thus releasing the memory ?